# How to read application/pdf content type from HttpClient response and return it

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API which successfully connects to another Web API using `HttpClient`. A `GET` method from the second Web API returns an *application/pdf* content-type.

I can see the content-type of the response at the debugger, using:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("{url}")
```

The question is, how can I read that stream and successfully return it in my own get method?

Preferably, the method type should be `IHttpActionResult`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward the content on and also get all the necessary details from the response of the other request

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction() {

    //...code removed for brevity

    var response = await client.GetAsync("{url}");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        message.Content = response.Content;
        return ResponseMessage(message);
    }

    return BadRequest(); //or some other status response.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.